# why expect statements in setTimeout not run

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, settimeout, sinon

My codes:

```
  before(function _before(){
    this.spyLog = sinon.spy(this.myOBJ.log, 'warn');
  });

  after(function _after(){
    this.spyLog.restore();
  });

  it('should', sinon.test(function() {
    const stubFindOne = this.stub(this.myOBJ, 'findOne');
    stubFindOne.returns(bluebird.reject(new Error('Should have failed')));
    this.myOBJ.toBeTestedFunction({});
    setTimeout(function _expect() {
      console.log('++++++++++++ 1 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
      console.log('this.spyLog', this.spyLog.args);
      expect(this.spyLog.args[0][0].toString()).to.be.equal('Error: Should have failed');
      console.log('++++++++++++ 2 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
    }, 100);
  }));
```

Why `_expect` function not run? Thanks

**UPDATE**
Tried the following codes, but got `Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded`. I think this is because `done` not called. I need `this.myOBJ.toBeTestedFunction({});` finish running and then run the expectations. How to fix the code?

```
  it('should', sinon.test(function(done) {
    const stubFindOne = this.stub(this.myOBJ, 'findOne');
    stubFindOne.returns(bluebird.reject(new Error('Should have failed')));
    this.myOBJ.toBeTestedFunction({});
    setTimeout(function _expect() {
      console.log('++++++++++++ 1 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
      console.log('this.spyLog', this.spyLog.args);
      expect(this.spyLog.args[0][0].toString()).to.be.equal('Error: Should have failed');
      console.log('++++++++++++ 2 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
          done();
    }, 100);
  }));
```

**UPDATE**

My following codes work. but how to improve it?

```
  it('should', sinon.test(function() {
    const stubFindOne = this.stub(this.myOBJ, 'findOne');
    stubFindOne.returns(bluebird.reject(new Error('Should have failed')));
    return new bluebird.Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
      this.myOBJ.tobetestedFunction();
      resolve();
    })
    .delay(1000)
    .then(() => {
      expect(this.spyLog.args[2][0].toString()).to.be.equal('Error: Should have failed');
    });
  }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, the test case is over before any asynchronous code (such as the callback to `setTimeout`) can run.  Add a `done` parameter to the `it` call, and call `done()` at the end of the `setTimeout` callback.

That said, I figured I'd go back and put together a code sample of what I'm saying, which got me to look closer at your code...  This looks like it's going to end up giving you trouble.  It looks like you're anticipating some asynchronous events to bring your expectations in line, but rather than controlling for execution of those events just saying "eh, they should be done within 100 ticks..."  It's not a good plan.

**THAT** said, it would look something like

```
it('should', sinon.test(function(done) {
    const stubFindOne = this.stub(this.myOBJ, 'findOne');
    stubFindOne.returns(bluebird.reject(new Error('Should have failed')));
    this.myOBJ.toBeTestedFunction({});
    setTimeout(function _expect() {
      console.log('++++++++++++ 1 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
      console.log('this.spyLog', this.spyLog.args);
      expect(this.spyLog.args[0][0].toString()).to.be.equal('Error: Should have failed');
      console.log('++++++++++++ 2 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
      done();
    }, 100);
  }));
```

**UPDATE** - You mention that adding `done` didn't work (timeout error); this is almost certainly because the `sinon.test` wrapper you've put around your function is getting in your way.  I'm not familiar with `sinon` (and a quick google did not turn up documentation for the `test` method), but in general what you would need is for the function returned by `sinone.test` to (1) take a `done` parameter, and (2) pass that as the first argument to the callback it wraps.  Putting a `done` parameter in your function apparently doesn't make that happen.  You'd have to consult the `sinon` docs.  (The jasmine feature you're trying to use is "asynchronous tests", but since `sinon` tries to be framework-agnostic I'm not sure if/how they address this.  Maybe just something about test methods that take additional parameters?)

Regarding your follow-up question about why this isn't a good test approach:  Putting real-time constraints on events not coded in a real-time computing environment is never a good idea.  If it took 250 ticks for the conditions to be met, is that really a test failure?  If so you're testing performance - not functionality - and even then, what you have here is a test that could pass on some hardware and fail on other hardware, or test "some of the time"... Not really the behavior you want from an automated test suite.

Plus those asynchronous events you're waiting on are almost certainly outside code whose behavior your test depends on - in which case it's not a proper unit test.

Doing this kind of test "the right way" is noticeably more difficult, as you would mock the external dependencies and use the mocked responses to advance your test toward evaluation of expectations

Comment: could you please give more details about `this is not a good plan`?

Comment: yes. I agree. but this is my job to write tests for existing codes, which I should not change now. How to write a proper unit test for the async function?